# Recurrent excel count

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Is there a more elegant way to do this in excel?

> =(IF(ISBLANK(O3); 0; O3-P3) +  IF(ISBLANK(O4); 0; O4-P4) +  IF(ISBLANK(O5); 0; O5-P5) + IF(ISBLANK(O6); 0; O6-P6) +
>   IF(ISBLANK(O7); 0; O7-P7) + IF(ISBLANK(O8); 0; O8-P8) +
>   IF(ISBLANK(O9); 0; O9-P9) + IF(ISBLANK(O10); 0; O10-P10))

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try something like

```
=SUMIF(O3:O10,">0")-SUMIF(O3:O10,">0",P3:P10)
```

If you are trying to sum Column O - Column P **if** Column O has a value.